# Asynchronous JavaScript to fetch remote JSON data with promises and generators

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, generator

I am trying to figure out how to do async calls using promises and generators (without 3rd party libraries). Most of the examples I found on the Internet are either incomplete or confusing (at least to me), so I decided to try and write the code myself.

I would really appreciate it if someone could review the code and provide comments and suggestions for improving it.

```
function getJSON(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const https = require("https");
        try {
            https.get(url, (response) => {
                let data = "";
                response.on("data", (part) => {
                    data += part;
                });
                response.on("end", () => {
                    try {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        reject("Error parsing data");
                    }
                });
            }).on("error", () => {
                reject("Error downloading data");
            });
        }
        catch(e) {
            reject("Error: " + e.message);
        }
    });
}

function request(generator) {
    var iterator = generator();
    function process(result) {
        if (result.done) {
            return;
        }
        const value = result.value;
        if (value instanceof Promise) {
            value.then(
                (data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    process(iterator.next());
                }
            )
            .catch(
                err => {
                    iterator.throw(err);
                }
            );
        }
    }
    try {
        process(iterator.next());
    } 
    catch(e) {
        iterator.throw(e);
    }
}

function *DataGenerator() {
    try {
        yield getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
        yield getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2");
        // yield getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"); // Parsing error
        // yield getJSON(""); // Domain name error
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

// Run

console.log("Before");
request(DataGenerator);
console.log("After");
```

This is also available as [a repo](https://github.com/armin-meth/asyncjs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks pretty good - like a nice application of generators and iterators for promises.

The only thing I could think of that could be updated is the `iterator` variable in the `request()` function could be declared with the [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) statement, since it doesn't appear to be re-assigned (unless I am missing something).

> ```
> var iterator = generator();
> ```

Then in that nested function `process()`, did you ever see the first conditional (i.e. `result.done`) have a *truthy* value? I tried running it a few times but never saw that occur...

> ```
> function process(result) {
>     if (result.done) {
>         return;
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Why do not use async / await functions? Its just syntactic sugar for promises / generators. Check this vanilla JS snippet, is live:

```js
var url1 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2'
var url2 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3'

async function mimicSyncInside () {
  console.log('Before')
  console.log(await fetch(url1).then(resp => resp.json()))
  console.log(await fetch(url2).then(resp => resp.json()))
  console.log('After')
}

mimicSyncInside()
```

Comment: There are many reasons. One of them is to better understand async/await (take a look behind the scenes sort of thing). Also, it is not either/or type of thing (eg. if you want to parallelize async/await tasks you need to use Promise.all) so depending on situation one might actually prefer using promises and generators over async/await.

Comment: BTW, to mimic the same behavior, the  aync/await code should be `console.log('Before')` then the async function with await tasks and then `console.log('After')`

Comment: And your code works? In this order? Before - post1 - post2 - after?